# NFS ACLs do not apply to root

Tags: access-control-list, nfs4

I've been using CIFS for my networking for the longest time, and I'd like to use NFS for my Linux to Linux file distribution. I've got a share drive that I've set a sticky group on, which appears to work okay when mounted via NFS except when root is writing.

So on the fileserver there is a directory called media that I've performed  [applying the ACLs](http://brunogirin.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/shared-folders-in-ubuntu-with-setgid.html) `setfacl -d -m u::rwx,g::rwx,o::r-x Media` on, so it looks like this:

```
drwsrwsrwx+ 16 chrishunter users  4096 Sep 25 06:10 Media
```

and performing actions works as expected:

```
chrishunter@server:/media/disk1/Media$ touch file
chrishunter@server:/media/disk1/Media$ sudo touch file2
[sudo] password for chrishunter: 
chrishunter@server:/media/disk1/Media$ sudo su
root@server:/media/Media# touch file3
root@server:/media/Media# ls -ltra file*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 chrishunter users 0 Sep 26 05:51 file
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root        users 0 Sep 26 05:51 file2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root        users 0 Sep 26 05:52 file3
```

Now mounting via NFS doesn't appear to apply the ACLs so that when I execute a sudo touch file it looks like this:

```
chrishunter@client:/mnt/Media$ touch file
chrishunter@client:/mnt/Media$ sudo touch file2
[sudo] password for chrishunter: 
chrishunter@client:/mnt/Media$ sudo su
root@client:/mnt/Media# touch file3
root@client:/mnt/Media# ls -ltra file*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 chrishunter users 0 Sep 26 06:09 file
-rw-r--r-- 1 root        users 0 Sep 26 06:10 file2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root        users 0 Sep 26 06:10 file3
```

So it appears that NFS4 should propagate it to the client automatically, and by running `nfs4_getfacl Media` I can see the permissions:

```
A::OWNER@:rwaDxtTcCy
A::GROUP@:rwaDxtcy
A::EVERYONE@:rxtcy
A:fdi:OWNER@:rwaDxtTcCy
A:fdi:GROUP@:rwaDxtcy
A:fdi:EVERYONE@:rxtcy
```

Now this says to me [by following the man](http://linux.die.net/man/5/nfs4_acl) that really, all permissions should be inherited, but in this case it isn't.

Notes to show it should be mounted with the ACLs in place.

```
chrishunter@server:/media/disk1/Media# tune2fs -l /dev/dm-0 | grep "Default mount options:"
Default mount options:    acl

chrishunter@server:/media/disk1/Media# mount |grep media
/dev/mapper/vg1-lv1 on /media/disk1/Media type ext4 (rw,acl)
```

**Update:**
Added the content of exports as this was a potential issue.

```
/media/Media 192.168.0.0/24(rw,no_root_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000,sync,no_subtree_check‌​)
```

Answer (score 0):

Classic NFS handles the root user specially.  You might try setting the `no_root_squash` option in your exports file on the server.  See `man exports`

Comment: But why would root not follow the ACLs defined? Surely with an ACL defining an inherited group would force that group to be inherited whether it the root was squashed or otherwise?

Comment: For security reasons root has historically been handled specially.  If NFS is translating/squashing `root` to the `nobody` user then the only ACLs that would apply for `root` would be those for `nobody`.  If you want to test this, create a directory owned by `nobody` and see if `root` can write to it.

Comment: So I do already have `no_squash_root` in my exports, so I don't believe this is the issue.

From exports:
   
 `/media/Media 192.168.0.0/24(rw,no_root_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000,sync,no_subtree_check)`